# How should different MVPs share the data

Tags: java, guava, mvp

Imagine I have got two 'components' following MVP pattern:
1: MyTableMVP (responsible to list Persons in table)
2: MyFormMVP (responsible to show Person in form)

Could you kindly help me to find elegant, right way to interchange data between different parts of my application?
I can use Bus, e.g. EventBus from guava, to Presenters (or/and views) interchange..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about using RX ? 
You can also have one MVP containing the other one maybe